# Is there a simple Python 3 way of making parallel for loop like in Java?

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork-join, ray

I come from Java. In Java 8 and above we have Concurrency API (Executor Service, Countdown Latch, Cyclic Barrier, Parallel Stream API). Is there any simple API like this in Python 3? I found only a lot of ugly code, where everyone is reinventing the wheel like fork join operation on hard-coded specific dict or list with custom code.

Lets say I have a dict with 50 000 elements and it contains group_id integer. I want to count how many elements are there in each group.

Something like this, but I want to make it nice, clean & parallel:

```
import collections

dataset_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)

for img, group_id in dataset:
    dataset_dict[classes[group_id]] += 1

print(dataset_dict)
```

The best I have found is Ray library in Python 3, but the API is very low level and not up to par with other modern languages. With the boom of lambdas and PyTorch / Keras machine learning in Python, progress in Typescript and overhaul since Java 8, I really need something like that in Python 3.

Can you provide some simple example for above code? I tried something with Ray, which seems the most simple. But the problem is writing increments in shared variable. Perhaps you know a better, more modern API for Python 3.

The expected behavior is that the 50 000 elements will be split by number of CPUs. Each thread will sum up the group count and then it will join the results into a final result. I think it could be just a simple Fork Join pool in this case. I want a perfect clean code, easily readable. So you just read the code and you get that "aha" moment like it's simple, but also smart, because the beauty is in the simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One somewhat fundamental difference between Python and Java is that Python has a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). This makes it a little more difficult to implement low level threading in the same way that you would for Java for example.

In Python, parallelism is typically achieved through multiple processes. [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) is the built in library which generally wraps the process of spawning multiple processes and shared memory objects. Note there's also an asyncio library which provides coroutines but doesn't provide true parallelism (user level cooperative multi-tasking)

Ray is a full distributed system so it can help to parallelize/distribute python code across an cores on a single machine, or across a full cluster. With Ray, you could use a [Parallel Iterator](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/iter.html) instead of a list, and wrap your dataset_dict in an [actor](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/actors.html). It might look something like:

```
dataset_iter = from_items(dataset)
dataset_iter.for_each(lambda x: ray.get(dataset_dict.increment.remote(x)))
# This line starts the processing
list(dataset_iter.gather_async())
```

and `dataset_dict` would look something like

```
import collections
@ray.remote
class Counter:
 def __init__(self):
  self.counter = collections.Counter()

 def increment(self, key):
  self.counter[key] += 1

dataset_dict = Counter.remote()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! At least I can wrap my head around this Ray syntax. Actor model is a bit overkill for simple operation, but scalable solution. So in real world case, if I have PyTorch dataset in CSV or DB: Database driver will provide data in Python data structure. Then I need convert to Ray structure. Calculate stuff. Then construct a Tensor with individual elements from the dataset. This overhead problem will arise in around 5 places during the process. It's like computing on GPU, where you need data transfer. But I guess this is the best what Python have until we have GraalVM.